# Fault handling for a nested method call

Tags: jolie

I have a service, whose skeleton code is below. I have a fault handler installed globally in "init" that catches the faults thrown from the methods. Now, in the addP method, I am calling another method findByPId, present in the same service. It throws the same "data not found" fault if the pid is not present. This call is being made from within the scope(findId) in the addP method. So I expect the fault thrown by the findById method to be caught in the findId scope. But it is being caught by the main install present in "init".

How can I resolve this problem?

`
service AService{
execution { concurrent }

```
inputPort Input1 {
    location: "socket://localhost:8203"
    protocol: http { format = "json" }
    interfaces: PInterface
}

outputPort Output1 {
    location: "socket://localhost:8203"
    protocol: http { format = "json" }
    interfaces: PInterface
}

init {
    install( DataNotFound=>
        println@Console( "Main: Data not found!!" )();
        throw (DataNotFound, "Sorry!! Data not found for the given input.")
    );
}

main {
    [addP (request) (response) {
        println@Console( "Add P")()

        scope(findId) {
            install( DataNotFound=>
                println@Console( "addP: Data not found!! New value can be added." )()
            )

            println@Console( "Before calling findByPId : ")()
            findByPId@Output1 (request.pId)(responseData)
            println@Console( "Response from findByPId : " + responseData.pName )();
        }
        response.message = "New record added successfully!!" 
    }]
    [findByPId (request) (response) {
        readFile@File( {
            filename = pathToPFile
            format = "json"
        } )( data )
        for ( i = 0, i < #data.p, i++ ) {
            toUpperCase@StringUtils(data.p[i].pId)(existingPId)
            toUpperCase@StringUtils(request)(requestPId)
            if(existingPId  == requestPId) {
                response << data.p[i]
            }
        }
        if(response.pName == null) {
            throw ( DataNotFound, "Sorry!! data not found for the given input")
        } else {
            println@Console( "Response from findByPId : " + response.pName )()
        }
    }]

}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
 if(response.pName == null) {
```

in jolie null is not a keyword and it does not represent anything special.
So, in that line you are just testing that `response.pName` is equal to something that does not exist, that is a `void` type in jolie. If in the response pName is an empty string, the condition == is not satisfied because you are testing an empty string and a void, thus it is a false.

concluding: the line `throw ( DataNotFound, "Sorry!! data not found for the given input")` is never triggered, this is why the global fault handler is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works well when the findByPId method is in a separate service and is called with say, findByPId@Helper. It is not returning and empty string. I will anyway make note of the usage of null.

Answer (score 0):

Your block

```
[ findByPId (request) (response) { ... } ]
```

is throwing a fault that is not handled by a scope within the body of `findByPId` (the `...`). That means that:

1. the fault `DataNotFound` is going to be returned to the caller (in your case the body of `addP`);
2. afterwards, that same fault is going to be propagated to the main scope, where you have installed your handler during `init`.

Point (2) is done to allow you to monitor that a fault has been thrown in case you want to do something with it. In your case I don't think that you should be doing anything really, so your handler in `init` should just be a `nullProcess`. The point where you should handle the `DataNotFound` fault is the body of your `addP` (as you are already correctly doing).

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the complete flow works well when I have the findByPId operation in a separate service such as findByPId@Helper and returns the fault to the addP method and allows me to add the non-existent entry. The issue is occuring when the output port is the same service. @fmontesi, I think since the findByPId method is in the same service, it is going to the init block directly although there is a handler in the addP method. I have a print statement in the handler of addP and that is not executed. Seems the scope(findId) is not overriding the init scope in this flow.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Jolie are you using? Also, could you write a minimalistic example that triggers the behaviour and doesn't use files? It'd be helpful for testing.

Comment: Jolie version is 1.10.5. Sure, will try to provide the sample code that you ask.